# How to Grow a Div notification bar from bottom-right position of the page when user scrolls down

Tags: jquery, notifications

i code for it but there is a mistake which i am not being able to capture. so here is my full code for that. here is my js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/xdcvC/

i was trying to grow a div from bottom-right of the page when user scroll down and when user scroll up then reverse effect will occur. could not understand where made the mistake

### my html

```
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>

<div id="slidebox">

    <p>More in Technology & Science (4 of 23 articles)</p>
    <h2>The Social Impact of Scientific Research and new Technologies</h2>
    <a class="more">Read More »</a>
</div>
```

### my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == ($('body').height() - $(window).height()))
        {
            // show container
            $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({
                'height':'100px',
                'width':'400px',
                left:($(window).width()-400)+'px',
                'opacity':'1'}, { queue: false, duration: 500, easing: 'easeInCubic' });          
        }
        else
        {
            $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({
                'height':'0px',
                'width':'0px',
                left:($(window).width()-400)+'px',
                'opacity':'0'},{queue: false, duration: 500});          
        }
    });

$('#slidebox').bind('click',function()
{

$('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px','opacity':'0'},{queue: false, duration: 500}); 

});

});
```

### my css

```
#slidebox{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-top:3px solid #E28409;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;

    -moz-box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    opacity:0;
}
#slidebox p, a.more{
    font-size:11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#555;
}
a.more{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#E28409;
}
a.more:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#slidebox h2{
    color:#E28409;
    font-size:18px;
    margin:10px 20px 10px 0px;
}
```

### Fixed CODE which works fine

### HTML

```
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>
Hello<br/>

<div id="slidebox">

    <p>More in Technology & Science (4 of 23 articles)</p>
    <h2>The Social Impact of Scientific Research and new Technologies</h2>
    <a class="more">Read More »</a>
</div>
```

### JS code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
    {
        // show container
        $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({
            'height':'100px',
            'width':'400px',
            'opacity':'1'}, { queue: false, duration: 500 });          
    }
    else
    {
        $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({
            'height':'0px',
            'width':'0px',
            'opacity':'0'},{queue: false, duration: 500});          
    }
});

$('#slidebox').on('click', function() {
    $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({
            'height':'0px',
            'width':'0px',
            'opacity':'0'},{queue: false, duration: 500});   
});
```

### CSS CODE

```
#slidebox{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-top:3px solid #E28409;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;

    -moz-box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    opacity:0;
}
#slidebox p, a.more{
    font-size:11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#555;
}
a.more{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#E28409;
}
a.more:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#slidebox h2{
    color:#E28409;
    font-size:18px;
    margin:10px 20px 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Give your slidebox css `right:0px` then you just have to animate the height, width and opacity rather than trying to figure out the left

Comment: @ Pete i did that but did not fix the problem. look at my fiddle link.

Comment: see this line : if($(window).scrollTop() == ($('body').height() - $(window).height())) it never become equal. why?

Comment: try this: `if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())` - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/xdcvC/5/ - just removed the easing effect as it isn't included in the fiddle

Comment: @ Pete thanks for your help. i like to know when i add easing effect then it just stop working. long time back i work with easing effect in fiddle and that works but now did not work.

Comment: when i add the below line then also script stop working.
$('#slidebox').bind('click',function()
{
    
        $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({
            'height':'0px',
            'width':'0px',
            'opacity':'0'},{queue: false, duration: 500});          

        });
    
});  what is wrong in my script.

Comment: try using `on` instead of `bind` - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/xdcvC/7/